# Fluent validation for httpget request webapi core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetCustomerById(int id)
        {
               var data = await _customerService.GetCustomerById(id);
                return Ok(data);
        }
```

how can we implement fluent validation for request parameter - id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it like this :

```
RuleFor(id => id).LessThan(100).GreaterThan(0);
```

You don't need FluentValidtion to validate the request, It's an Attribute Routing. It helps you to not process invalid request.

```
[HttpGet("GetCustomerById/{id:int:min(1)}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCustomerById(int id)
{
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to validate id parameter value- i.e zero, null, maxvalue using fluent validation

Comment: @NileshButani; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.